# How to call field label & values in custom content type page template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have created a custom `page--mycontent-type.page.tpl` for customizing display with html tags classes & attributes.
I'am unable to call that content type fields & their label.
I've tried these to print values but not worked for me.

1. `<?php print render($content['field_name']); ?>`
2. `<?php print render($page['content']['field_name']); ?>`
3. `<?php print render($fields['field_introduction']->content); ?>`

Please suggest me what code call the actual fields & label. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: page tpl's are quite high level and after all of the content has been pulled together for rendering. If you want to change things on a specific content type you might be better using node--mycontent-type.tpl.php. Or is there a specific reason you need the node fields in the page.tpl

Comment: Yes I have some specific reason to call field's label & its value individually and add many classes attributes some javascript and extra headings that I'am unable to do by field formatter class module.

Comment: If you’re not preprocessing then it won’t matter what template you’re using. I don’t see how a page template changes this vs a node template. These variables don’t exist at the page level.

Comment: The question wasn't very clear but the reason I suggested it would be in a page.tpl within $content you'd only have the regions. Within the node tpl you'd have the actual node fields within $content (plus $node) which looked to be what he was after

Comment: Thanks, gentleman for your suggestions.....The reason being I am asking this question because my design is ready with html css javascript jquery.....the problem I am facing in customizing it to drupal 7 theme is that the Labels & values has lots of css classes & attributes & some inline javascript. So I am unable to put those classes javascript by content type manage display field formatter method. Please suggest me some solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the objective of adding classes to fields in a node (as you made clear in your comment) you can use `hook_node_view` to intercept the node and then you can change the markup of your fields.
You can find detailed examples [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x).